# How long would it take for a brilliant person to decipher/crack an alien language and how to use its technology?

Tags: technology, culture, aliens, language

Consider this:

A fallen spaceship is approached by a person of very high intelligence. Think of someone really really smart, like top 50 in the world.

How long would take for such a person to grasp another culture´s language and how their technology works? Would it even be possible? Or what would take to make it possible?

Even if we consider that the person making the analysis comes from the same planet, would be possible to crack the language? I live in the same planet as you guys and I cant read or understand any other language than the ones I already know.

Narrowing it down:

The person that makes the analysis has "immortal" lifespan. Comes from highly advanced culture, like elders, or the first ones in the universe. Member of a society extremely advanced that in the past was responsible for seeding other civilizations into existence.

Now he must analyze one artifact (the spaceship) that was made from a civilization formed by descendants (not directly) of his own.

Both civilizations didn't have any previous contact. But the beings are basically the same, lets go with essentially humans.

Is it cheating saying that the elder has super-intelligence and therefore can crack the language and linguistic systems and symbology of the newer civilization?

Comment: It depends on how such race communicates. If it is intelligent insects which use chemical signals, it would hard. I believe this is unanswerable.

Comment: @PeterMasiar good point. If the question can be narrowed down to a specific control method then estimates can be made. As it is the technology could be controlled by pressing buttons, by releasing combinations of chemicals into the air, by adopting a particular posture, or any from the long list of things we couldn't possibly think of.

Comment: Also the probability of success is strongly linked to the ability of the investigator to work out how to recognise "self destruct" *very* quickly.

Comment: It also depends on what communication is available: only technical manuals, l337-speak IRC logs or proper literature. All have different distribution of words that the analyst would use to find the content.

Comment: Not only that the 'brilliant' person in question could depend very highly on the training they've had.

Comment: Thanks for the input guys, I added a few things to the original post to narrow it down a bit.

Comment: Or maybe some autistic savage savant (not the sharpest knife in the drawer) can be able to count clicks and realize they speak in Morse. Or some blind person has some advantage, because seeing is not important for those aliens. Or whatever you can imagine. Or my favorite alien, living planet-size ocean.

Comment: @PeterMasiar Hi, and thanks for the input. I had thought of this elder person being a savant because I watched a tv show other day about them. He could have superb linguistic skills/code cracking and figure out at least the basics, even tough being inept at many other things. Just like those people who make instantaneous calculations. +1 for thinking alike and suggesting some disability as an advantage.

Comment: "Is it cheating saying that the elder has superintelligence" -- that depends. If he just has extremely good memory and reasoning ability, so he learns *faster* than a normal human being could, I don't think it's a problem. If the ability is essentially magical -- he has never seen Chinese writing before, but can pick up a book in Chinese and immediately know how to read it -- then yes, I think it's cheating.

Comment: Why not have the fallen spaceship be an automatic survey ship with A.I. that analyzed and successfully decoded our digital satellite transmissions. It's logs/records contain their interpretations of our world. So it will be like a reverse Rosetta stone. Like the ship computer making a comment (in its own language) about a picture of a lion or an entry about a picture of our formula for area of circle. Thousands of earth pictures with corresponding alien language comments you can just have your brilliant (hero?) cross-reference repeating alien symbols.

Comment: FWIW...the 'very high intelligence' is likely a hindrance here, outside of 'quick to learn'.  Language (culture) tend to be related to perception, creativity, and intuition...which some of the most intelligent people in the world tend to struggle with (fiction, but Sheldon in 'the Big Bang Theory' is an obvious example, Russel Crowe in a beautiful mind).  I would give an intuitive person better odds here when it comes to language.  We are social beings, a group of people would be able to put this together far far quicker (assuming it was possible).  ANy reason you are stuck to one?

Comment: "Is it cheating saying that the elder has super-intelligence and therefore can crack the language and linguistic systems and symbology of the newer civilization?"  I don't think this is cheating at all.  You could create a scenario where all language is derivative from the progenitor race's language and therefore 'cracking the code' is not all that difficult for them.

Comment: Thanks to you all for replying and for giving me new views to consider, @RoyalCanadianBandit, @ tls, @ Twelfth, @ James... I was actually leaning towards what James says, and I liked the importance of the intuitive aspect mentioned by Twelfth. But you all gave me something new to consider, thanks!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It may be impossible. For example, consider the ancient Minoan script known as [Linear A](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_A), which we have been unable to decipher. We know the ancient Minoans were human beings and quite a lot about how they lived. They must have had words for things like "house", "farm", "mother", "child", and so on, but this has been no help in understanding their written language. For an alien species, even the most basic concepts about life and communication might be completely different, so we could be even worse off than with Linear A.

There are a couple of ways in which it might be plausible for an intelligent human to learn the alien language:

- There is a lot of material to work with. The spacecraft might have a massive archive that includes audio and video as well as text. If a sufficiently intelligent alien had access to the complete library of Netflix, it could probably learn to speak English even if it had no other contact with us. (In the process, it might get some highly misleading impressions of our culture...)
- The archive is *intended* to be understood. There might be a non-intelligent computer system which is designed to teach aliens the concepts of their language, using pictures and (hopefully) universal concepts such as mathematics.

It has been [estimated](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/magazine-23407265) that it takes 1765 hours for an adult to learn fluent English from scratch. (Children learn much more quickly.) At 8 hours a day, 7 days a week, it would take about 8 months. So this would be the *minimum* length of time to learn fluent alien-language, given a sophisticated and cooperative teaching system.

If we were trying to analyse recordings the aliens had made for themselves and reverse-engineer the rules of their language, it might take much longer -- years or decades would be plausible.

Comment: Or, if they left a type of Rosetta Stone with at least one current Earth-based language and a mapping to their own.

Comment: If we're talking about someone with an extremely high IQ though, the time to learn fluent English may be cut by quite a lot. It's hard to say by how much. Maybe more than 75%

Comment: I disagree that "Children learn much more quickly" - it took me (as a child) about two years to learn English, even while working 12 hours a day, and ended up with the vocabulary of a two-year-old.

Comment: "universal concepts such as mathematics. " May not be true. Maybe the aliens used completely different axioms at the beginning and their mathematics is quite different from ours, although the results may produce similar effects (such as allowing the development of advanced physics etc).

Comment: Physical science gives universal values that don't change by culture - Hydrogen is hydrogen. If we found their version of the Periodic Table we would get quite a jump start on decoding.  The Classic SF story "Omnilingual" by H Beam Piper is a good example of this. Hogan's Inherit the Stars is another.

Comment: "There is a lot of material to work with". Too much information equals disinformation. If you have so much material there is high probability that it will contain some different accents, dialects, or even personal mannerisms, making it harder to spot patterns and crack the mystery. For example English form London Docs is not the same English as Oxford English. If a docker would talk to a professor they would probably understand each other, but someone who doesn't speak English would never figure out what they meant. So it may be better to have less data, but coming from more unified source.

Comment: @Aurast: meh. I have reasonably high IQ (or used to when I was a kid) and I am (and was) fairly poor at languages. IQ is somewhat correlated with being good at various mental tasks it doesn't directly test, just as they're somewhat correlated with each other, see much psychology literature. Some people are much faster than the average at learning languages, of course, I just doubt how well IQ predicts this.

Comment: @abcde yeah, I wouldn't say I know any 8 month olds who are fluent in English ^_^

Comment: @SteveJessop Google for "IQ and language learning". This has been the subject of research. But let's forget about IQ as it concerns this question. The question only specifies that the person is "brilliant". Assuming the author is working on some work of fiction, and given the scenario, he or she probably means the character has, among other gifts, extraordinary language aptitude.

Comment: Exactly on point @Aurast. The character is from the progenitor´s race, one of the first ones, so he has superhuman skills, including linguistics. I´m just trying to paint some better scenario so that he being superhuman doest equal the "magical/skill" solution (its magic).

Comment: Very good points you've raised. To be fair (albeit a bit nit-picky), English may be one of the most difficult languages to learn, let alone master - so it might not be the best standard for a 'minimum' length of time to learn a language.

Answer (score 12):

**Depends:** Take the [Voynich manuscript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voynich_manuscript) as an example. While we know it was not written by aliens, we (as in, humanity) started trying to crack it in the early 1900s and just recently we [may found out how to crack it](http://www.beds.ac.uk/news/2014/february/600-year-old-mystery-manuscript-decoded-by-university-of-bedfordshire-professor).

[Language is hard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_talker) and using a different language is always a good idea as a cipher (see link at beginning).

Being [Czech](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Czech_language), I can assure you that if that alien language is really different from the language the "elder" speaks, it could give him/her/it a hard time cracking it. Just as a joke:

> Příliš žluťoučký kůň úpěl ďábelské ódy

That sentence above is a pangram in Czech, featuring all the diacritic symbols in Czech. And talk about luck, my language uses the same alphabet as English language does. If we switch to Russian, a language from the same family as Czech, the fun increases:

> Эх, чужак, общий съём цен шляп (юфть) – вдрызг!

To return to the subject, I was talking about living languages the whole time. The alien language will be even harder — at the level of the manuscript I linked to above. You will naturally make the assumption that if there is picture of monkey with some text below, the text will be about... monkeys. But you could be wrong:
[image: The cover of the movie *The Hangover: Part II*. There is a monkey prominently shown in the centre of the image, with no surrounding text mentioning monkeys.]
<sup>*[Image source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Hangover_Part_II)*</sup>

That's why you need a [Rosetta stone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rosetta_Stone) to be found at the place. Otherwise, the cracking might take you forever.

Comment: Very good! I know about the manuscript and the rosetta stone. I agree that cracking a language without context seems impossible. I´m just fishing for different views or how it could be done in ways that dont sound too much like "how convenient for him"...

Comment: I would not describe neither Voynich or Egypt hieroglyphs cracking was "convenient". But without finding text *clearly* about some content, or something like Rosetta stone is almost impossible

Comment: When I used convenient, I was referring to the fact that I dont want to give the person doing the analysis a solution that would clearly show how the odds are being pushed in his favor. You know, like the author helping the main character survive some dire situation that no one survived before without a good enough reason. That is why I considered making him a savant, because it could perhaps allow for an unprecedented ability.

Comment: I was thinking about the same setup for my story (it also requires cracking of alien language). To me, the story would be more believable if you replace "elder" by group of scientists and let them make several incorrect guesses about the language (like the one with monkey)

Comment: @mcbecker If you want a plausible way for him to learn the language - he could always stumble upon some learning-program for alien babies. Something trivial which teaches a small child the basics of language and culture via simple games and conditioning... This could be universal enough to be as understandable for a human as an alien baby

Comment: @Falco Others suggested the same thing (alien baby learning device). But I cant get my mind around the fact that it feels to convenient or just too lucky to stumble upon it. I know it is an alien ship but that kind of device might not fit in a scout vessel or military ship or even in a spaceship of a race whose members have a extremely long lifespan. So, no babies on board.

Comment: @mcbecker The same device could also be used for rehabilitation in a medical setting. If someone had a stroke or other heavy trauma, he may need to relearn the whole language, how to walk and much more. If the medical technology is advanced, they could maybe use this if a part of the brain was destroyed. The brain could probably be regrown, but the patient would have to relearn everything which was saved in this region...

Comment: @Falco Thats cool, I would change and expand on it, like this: The medical device analyzes the investigators brain and decides it is badly damaged and without the appropriate knowledge (because it is different but simmilar enough). It works to restore it to full working condition. It may grant some ability like psionics while it affects the owner´s original brain. The investigator lost good part of his memory, or has mental disorders, etc.. This could actually work, it could erase the sense of self from the investigator (because it is used for treatment of clone soldiers).. GOOD! Thanks!

Comment: Oooh.  Last time I checked on the Voynich manuscript, there was nothing.  Thanks for the link!  The press has overblown his progress (of course), but I'm skimming his paper now.

Comment: Google Translate can't find a meaning for *žluťoučký*, but web search brings up the Wikipedia page for *pangram* in CZ, and some faces.  What does it mean?

Comment: Translated to English: "Too yellowish horse was crying out devil odes." Basically, it is nonsense even in Czech, but it showcases all diacritic symbols being used in Czech language

Comment: @PavelJanicek Let's say an alien recorded a phone call in the Czech Republic, then translates it into his language so he can learn Czech. He will get something like "Ty vole, di do prdele! Vole zase vole si to zvoral ty mrcho vole, to je jak u debilů hajzle!" which translates to "You ****, go **** *******! **** again **** you did it wrong, you ******* ****, it's like with *****, you ******!" Well, let's hope no alien tries to learn Czech from what he hears on the road... :)

Answer (score 4):

Language might well be impossible because there isn't enough information.

Technology is probably doable — in principle an artifact contains enough information to understand what and how it does.  There are 2 conditions:

1. You don't accidentally destroy the ship and/or kill yourself.  If you have no idea how a spaceship works (or what the warning signs say), accidentally turning on its nuclear/blackhole engines is a non-negligible risk.  Thing get worse if it has weapons or anti-intrusion self-destruct mechanisms.  Even a peaceful pro-safety life-support ship might do surprising things like violently ejecting lifeboats as soon as the hull is breached...

   OTOH an elder race probably does have full understanding of laws of physics  and possible power sources, and non-invasive scanning techniques.  Best scenario is atom-resolution scanning then safely playing with it inside a simulation.
2. It's not *too* advanced compared to your level.  Being a genius in an elder race helps, but a descendant race might be even more advanced...

   This wouldn't make it strictly impossible but the research can take unbounded time.

   I think the best example we have for how advanced technology can be "indistinguishable from magic" is our biology.

   - If you are Aristotle you're a genius in your time but won't even figure out how blood is pumped around by the heart...
   - With current instruments and knowledge we have a great overall picture,  productively study numerous low-level mechanisms and can develop interventions.  It did take observation on *millions* of *functioning* humans to get here.  (=> Having 1 spaceship might not be enough.  Chances are way worse if no longer works.)

     By now the principles of most biological "design" don't feel alien to us: pneumatics, electrical/chemical pathways, organs & subsystems with clear purpose — we can't build like that (esp. chemistry) but we feel the purpose of it all.
   - DNA is harder.  We're progressing steadily with reverse-engineering it but we have no idea how to *develop* it.  Unlike human software, it seems to be a big tangle of randomness that happened to work together — we have no idea how to approach a big modification (e.g. produce healthy humans with wings), except by horrendous trial-and-error for millions of years and trillions of victims...  For all we know, there may be no better way!
   - The brain is even harder.  Having instruments and low-level understanding is not enough.  We did reverse-engineer some fixed neural networks e.g. vision quite but we deeply have *no idea* how high-level cognition works.  At some point a lot of signals flow, "magic chaos" happens, and it *works*...  If you gave us perfect neural scans, even ones that we could simulate, we'd surely advance a lot on the low level but there is no guarantee we'll understand it.  That's what "designed by aliens" feels like.

Answer (score 4):

In James P Hogan's early novel *Inherit the Stars*, people find a lone individual in a space suit with some carrable equipment.  They start to figure out reading from technical labels: figure out what voltage the thing was designed to use, and you have a guess as to what the label at the power connector states. The dimensions of items are biased to the units of measurement.

In another famous story,  a library of technical journals is found. The use a wall hangings in the classrooms as a Rosetta Stone: the periodic table, illustrations of elementary mechanics, etc. The point of the story is that even with no common point to relate to culture, science and engineering form a universal common area of understanding.

Comment: That second story is "Omnilingual" by H. Beam Piper.

Comment: H.Beam Piper should be on everyone's reading list.

Answer (score 3):

do you want to understand their language, or their technology?  learning the technology could be easier then the language.  If you put me down in front of a switch board made by someone with a different language I can still hit switches to see what happens.  Even if you give me a complex system I can still dissect it and analyze it using my understanding of physics, which is universal, to translate it.  Learning the technology without the language is a far more achievable goal.

As to how long it takes, that depends on how advanced the two are, and what technology/knowledge gap may exist between them.

Comment: "I wonder what does this red button do..." AUTO-DESTRUCT IN TEN MINUTES "wow I wish I could understand that..." But anyway, +1 for pointing out that it would be faster to learn the tech by trial and error than the language

Comment: as a rule of thumb I NEVER hit the big red buttons.  Unless their really pretty, or big...or tempting..or..I must..not..press....oh what harm could it do?  excuse me one second I'm just going to try this one.. *BOOOM*

Comment: But what if to the aliens, small silver switches scream danger instead of big red buttons? You'd still be dead in seconds.

Comment: When I reverse engineer suspicious code I don't *just* hit buttons.  There are things one can do to protect themselves while experimenting.  For code that's running in a sandbox, mocking dangerious systems etc.  For hardware it may mean disconnecting the control panel from the hardware before you hit buttons and making sure the fuel is all emptied out before playing with the engine.  However, there *are* ways to explore and reverse engineer hardware intelligently without making things go boom.  so long as I don't press that pretty...pretty...button.........

Comment: @dsollen But what if the big red buttons are big exactly because you use them often? The smaller ones are for less executed tasks, so they dont need to be big?

Comment: Buttons: I have a power button on a drive swap cage that is small and flush with the panel. It is difficult to press with the tip of my little finger, and is usually operated with a pen or somesuch. A different species might find different things easy vs hard, so think the normal srart button is an emergency switch and the fuse reset and calebration controls are the things to press.

Comment: I joked about the buttons, but the truth is if your allowing buttons to actually activate something your insane.  There are valid reverse engineering tricks to avoid things blowing up.  Though I will admit if the technology gap is gigantic enough it may be safer to learn the language first because you wouldn't know how to safely reverse engineer the tech.  A monkey may not know how to remove batteries from the remote control death ray before hitting keys.